# Unable to establish second Raspberry Pi [WIFI Direct] to a device

Tags: android, raspberry-pi3, wifi-direct, wpa-supplicant

I have 2 Raspberry Pi and an Android Tablet and the Tablet is supposed to be controlling the Raspberry Pi via the webserver from the Pi. The Android Tablet has a Wifi Direct application and I was able to establish connection with one of the Pi. However when I tried to connect to the second device it doesn't established the connection.

Raspberry Pi wpa_supplicant.conf file (Devices name are raspberry and raspberry2 respectively):

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
driver_param=p2p_device=1
update_config=1
device_name=raspberry
device_type=1-0050F204-1
p2p_go_intent=10
p2p_go_ht40=1
country=SG

network{
...
}
```

wpa_cli outputs on Raspberry Pi 1 :

```
p2p_find 30
OK
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED
...
<3>P2P-DEVICE-FOUND AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF ..... //Android Tablet Details
<3>P2P-PROV-DISC-PBC_REQ AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF //Android Tablet Connection Request
<3>P2P-GO-NEG-REQUEST AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF dev_passwd_id=4

p2p_connect AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF pbc
<3>P2P-GO-NEG-SUCCESS role=cilent ...
<3>P2P-GROUP-FORMATION-SUCCESS
<3>P2P-GROUP-STARTED p2p-wlan0-0 client ssid="DIRECT-android-tablet" .... [PERSISTENT]
```

Connection has been established between the first Raspberry Pi and Android Tablet and I am able to view the webserver hosted by the Raspberry Pi.

wpa_cli outputs on Raspberry Pi 2:

```
p2p_find 30
OK
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED
        ...
<3>P2P-DEVICE-FOUND AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF ..... //Android Tablet Details
<3>P2P-INVITATION-RECEIVED sa=AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF go_dev_addr=AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF bsid=AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF unknown-network

p2p_connect AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF pbc
OK
```

Connection wasn't established with Raspberry Pi 2. So the question is am I doing something wrong on the Android application side or the configuration side of the Raspberry Pi.

Thank you for taking your time to read, I'm quite new to stackoverflow way of asking questions, do let me know what I should work on too! (Formats etc..)